# Django Signals how to create clone or duplicate objects?

Tags: django

I am building an notification system for send notifications blog subscribers and bog author. I am using Django post_save signals which creating notifications objects. Is it possible to create two separate notification objects or create an clone objects for my **BlogCommnet model**.

here is my code:

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
      blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
      #my others fields 
      #here signals starting
      def user_comment(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
            comment= instance
            blog = comment.blog
            sender = comment.user
            commnet_notes = comment.rejected_comment_notes
            comment_text = comment.comment
            
            if sender != blog.author and comment.is_published == "pending":
               notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=comment.blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")
               notify.save()

post_save.connect(BlogComment.user_comment, sender=BlogComment)
```

Right now it's creating only one notifications objects. see the picture:
[image]

I want it will create  another clone objects of it's orginal. is it possible ???

I tried this for create an duplicate objects but didn't work:

```
if sender != blog.author and comment.is_published == "pending":
               notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=comment.blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")
               notify.save()
               notify2 = notify
               notify2.save()
```

Comment: You can create 2 Notification instances? Though, I'm confused with your Notification model design since a notification is intended for one user, yet your model has a `sender`.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr yes exactly I want an clone of my Notification instances. I tried `notify2=notify, notify2.save() `but didn't work

Comment: Yea, that won't work because `notify2` is just referencing `notify`. It's not a "deep copy". What you should do is just do the same thing you did with `notify`. And technically, to create a notification, it should be `Notifications.object.create(...)`. Probably also want to rename your `Notifications` model to singular since you're working with just one model instance.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr  I tried this `Notifications.objects.create(notify)` and getting this error `'Notifications' object is not iterable'`

Comment: It should be this: `Notifications.objects.create(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=comment.blog.author, text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")`. Run this twice to create 2 objects. [API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create)

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr  I understood. My previous problems solved. Now it’s creating duplicate objects of it’s original. Now my problem is author and customer seeing the two objects at a time as my database saving duplicate objects of it’s original. is it possible to show only original objects to author and duplicate objects to customer. so they will see only one objects in html template??? see the picture:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235225/discussion-between-scratchnpurr-and-boyenec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Scratch'N'Purr give this solution on comment `Notifications.objects.create(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=comment.blog.author, text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")` and below solution also worked for me

```
 if sender != blog.author and comment.is_published == "pending":
               notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=comment.blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")
               notify.save()
               notify2 =Notifications.objects.create(blog=blog, sender=sender, receiver=comment.blog.author, text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")
               notify2.save()
```